# PySpark Transform an algorithm to UDF and apply it on a DataFrame

Tags: algorithm, list, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I wrote an algorithm that does something and prints the output. The input for my algorithm is a list with some integers.
Here is the sample input as a list.

`` `mylist = [5,6,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,28,40,41,42,43,44,55]` ``

and here is my algorithm

````
    ```     

tduration = 0
duration = 0
avg = 0
bottleneck = 0
y = 0
x = 0
while x<len(mylist)-4 and y<len(mylist)-1 :
  if mylist[x+4] == mylist[x]+4:
    y = x + 4
    print("MY LIST X = ",mylist[x])
    print("X = ", x)
    print ("Y = ", y)
    while True:
      if y==len(mylist)-1 or mylist[y+1] > mylist[y]+10:
        bottleneck = bottleneck + 1
        duration = mylist[y] - mylist[x] + 1
        tduration = tduration + duration
        avg = tduration/bottleneck
        x = y + 1
        print("MY LIST Y = " , mylist[y])
        print("Duration = " , duration)
        break
      else: 
        y = y + 1
  else: 
    x = x + 1
print("BottleneckCount = ", bottleneck,  "\nAverageDuration = ", avg)

 ```
````

Now I want to transform this "Algorithm" to a User Defined Function (UDF) in PySpark and then apply this UDF to a DataFrame with one column. There is one list in each row of this DataFrame. Sample DataFrame has 1 column and 2 rows. row1 is a list of `[10,11,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,33,45]` and row2 is a list of `[55,56,57,58,59,60,80,81,82,83,84,85,92,115]` so the UDF should be applied to each row of DataFrame separately and give the results for each row in another column. 
**Thank you in advance for your time and help. I will upvote your answers**

Comment: What do you want your function to return ?

Comment: I want it to return 2 numbers ("bottleneck" & "avg") that are being printed in the last line of the algorithm. print("BottleneckCount = ", bottleneck,  "\nAverageDuration = ", avg)     Thank you so much for your help and support. I really need  the answer. This is the last part of my 6-month project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you can do:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, ArrayType

def calculate(mylist):

    tduration = 0
    duration = 0
    avg = 0
    bottleneck = 0
    y = 0
    x = 0
    while x<len(mylist)-4 and y<len(mylist)-1 :

        if mylist[x+4] == mylist[x]+4:
            y = x + 4
            print("MY LIST X = ",mylist[x])
            print("X = ", x)
            print ("Y = ", y)
            while True:
                if y==len(mylist)-1 or mylist[y+1] > mylist[y]+10:
                    bottleneck = bottleneck + 1
                    duration = mylist[y] - mylist[x] + 1
                    tduration = tduration + duration
                    avg = tduration/bottleneck
                    x = y + 1
                    print("MY LIST Y = " , mylist[y])
                    print("Duration = " , duration)
                    break
                else:
                    y = y + 1
        else:
            x = x + 1
    return bottleneck, avg

# sample data frame to use
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        [[10,11,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,33,45]],
        [[55,56,57,58,59,60,80,81,82,83,84,85,92,115]],
    ],
    ['col1',]
)

df.show()

+--------------------+
|                col1|
+--------------------+
|[10, 11, 19, 20, ...|
|[55, 56, 57, 58, ...|
+--------------------+

# convert values to int  --- edit
f_to_int = F.udf(lambda x: list(map(int, x)))
df = df.withColumn('col1', f_to_int('col1'))

# create udf
func = F.udf(lambda x: calculate(x), ArrayType(IntegerType()))

# apply udf
df = df.withColumn('vals', func('col1'))

# create new cols
df = df.select("col1", df.vals[0].alias('bottleneck'), df.vals[1].alias('avg'))

df.show()

+--------------------+----------+----+
|                col1|bottleneck| avg|
+--------------------+----------+----+
|[10, 11, 19, 20, ...|         1|null|
|[55, 56, 57, 58, ...|         2|null|
+--------------------+----------+----+
```

Comment: Thank you so much would you please upvote my question so I will be able to upvote your answer.

Comment: done, didn't know this was a requirement. also please accept it for future readers.

Comment: I realized that the last column which is "avg" is getting NULL values. The reason is that "avg" values are not integers. They are "Doubles". Would you please solve this problem as well?! Thank you so much for your help and support.

Comment: if `type` is causing trouble, please check the edit, we not convert to integer first before applying the `calculation` function.

Comment: Thanks. I do not need to convert anything to int. The last column (in your Code above) which is "avg" is showing NULL and the reason is that "avg" values are double. I want it to show the "avg" column as double values. Maybe if you run the code once you will understand better what I mean.

Comment: I found out I should do this to get different types for the output.

Answer (score 0):

YOLO answered this question and it is a complete answer. The only problem is that in the last column for "avg", we are getting NULL values. 
I realized that I can solve this problem by using this "func" instead of that "func" in YOLO's answer.

```
import pyspark.sql.types as T
func = F.udf(lambda x: calculate(x), T.StructType(
        [T.StructField("val1", T.IntegerType(), True),
         T.StructField("val2", T.FloatType(), True)]))
```